# OPencv C++ Concatenate/merge/insert two vectors of type Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, insert, mat

I am trying to concatenate vectors and am running into some issues. Using the insert function I was able to combine two vectors of type `std::vector<keyPoint>` but run into issues when attempting to do the same process but to vectors of type `std::vector<Mat>`.

Te error is `No matching member function for call to 'begin, 'end'`

Code is as follows

```
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp1, kp2;
std::vector<Mat> desc1, desc2;
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
std::vector<Mat> descriptors;
//Add keypoints and descriptors found to master list
keypoints.insert(keypoints.end(),kp1.begin(),kp1.end());
keypoints.insert(keypoints.end(),kp2.begin(),kp2.end());

descriptors.insert(descriptors.end(),desc1.begin(),desc1.end());
descriptors.insert(descriptors.end(),desc2.begin(),desc2.end());
```

Looking for a solution or a work-around. 
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Concatenating vectors of Mats compiles fine under VS 2015.

Comment: You forgot to show us what `kp1`, `kp2`, `desc1` and `desc2` are. Also, show the full error message -- I'm pretty sure the compiler provides some additional context you didn't deem relevant, such as the variable in question and the types involved..

Comment: @DanMasek Thank for that  I will add kp1, kp2, desc1, and desc2. In regards to the error mesage that was the full extend of it. I was classified as a semantic issue by xcode bu that was it in regards to the error.

Comment: @C.Radford I'm not familiar with xcode, but is there some kind of compilation log? The compiler should be producing much more verbose output, I suspect the IDE is hiding it from you in some way. | Now that you've updated it, I don't really see a reason why this shouldn't compile.